# GitHub: Search for String Inside of a File in a Repo

Tags: github, github-api

**TLDR:** I want to use the GitHub search API to find a list of all repos with a "search-string" inside of the top-level Jenkinsfile. Does GitHub allow that?

I've read numerous SO posts and GitHub search/API docs including:

- [How to search for code in GitHub with GitHub API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132790/how-to-search-for-code-in-github-with-github-api)
- [How to search for code in github, with github API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652477/how-to-search-for-code-in-github-with-github-api)
- https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code

And can't find the answer to my issue.

I'm first trying to use the GitHub code search API to search for a specific substring (only two words with a dash joining them: "search-string") in a specific file, but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried numerous combinations of simple & advanced searches, but usually get zero results. I.e.

- 1 result (obvious): repo:repo/redacted
- 0 results: repo:repo/redacted search-string
- 0 results: search-string repo:repo/redacted filename:Jenkinsfile
- 0 results: search-string repo:repo/redacted in:Jenkinsfile

And quite a few more combos.

Once I get it working on the GitHub website, I'll convert it to an API call, which shouldn't be an issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's odd, the third string works for me using a similar string in my repository.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem where I was trying to use the GitHub search web interface to find instances of a particular filename in my code, which had a name including underscore characters and a number, like `my_image_asset_2.svg`.

Searching on that string within my repository (or organization) unexpectedly returned zero results (in the "Code" results type), using a search term like:

- `repo:repo/redacted my_image_asset_2.svg`

Even trimming out the number and extension from my search term still unexpectedly returned zero results:

- `repo:repo/redacted my_image_asset`

A workaround that finally stumbled on that got GitHub to return the code I was looking for was to (1) drop all punctuation characters from my filename, and (2) enclose the filename in quotes:

- `repo:repo/redacted "my image asset 2 svg"`

This might not be a perfect solution in all cases; I imagine it might also match filenames like `my-image-asset-2.svg`. But depending on your use case, it might be "good enough"?